# Win 11 how to add vs code to right click menu after instalation

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, right-click, regedit

No right click vs code menu after right click

Press Win + R
Type regedit into Run’s Open text box
go to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\vs_code\command
make new key vs_code
icon to (your vs code path)"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
defoult set a name to VS Code best editor
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YroXz.png)

add new key command
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGbQj.png)

and set the link to (your vs code path)"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe" .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2ycY.png)